# How use the hash in my custom login laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, hash, authentication

I am developing my own login and I have the following code

```
public function login(Request $request ) {
         $email = \Request::input('email');  
        $password = \Request::input('password');              
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))  
        {  
            //echo "success";  
            return redirect('home');  
        }  
        else {  
            return "fail";  
        }  
    }
```

And the CreateUserRequest

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nif' => 'required | max:9 ',
            'name' => 'required | max:255',
            'email' => 'required',
            'cognoms' => 'required | max:255',
            'birthday' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required | confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
            'municipios' => 'required | Integer|Min:1',
            'presentacion' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required'

        ];
    }

}
```

My register controller

```
public function registro(CreateUserRequest $request){ 

        $usuario = new User();
        $usuario->nif = \Request::input('nif');     
        $usuario->name = \Request::input('name');
        $usuario->cognoms = \Request::input('cognoms');
        $usuario->birthday = \Request::input('birthday');
        $usuario->email = \Request::input('email');
        $usuario->password= \Request::input('password');
        /**Foto del usuario**/ 
        $file = \Request::file('file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $fileName);
        $usuario->file = 'uploads/'.$fileName.'';
        $usuario->save();
        /**Asignamos el rol a la tabla intermedia***/
        $user = User::find($usuario->id);
        $user->roles()->attach(1);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

The model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['nif','name','cognoms','email', 'password','idempresa','id_poblacion','id_online',];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

     public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Empresa');
    }

     public function municipio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ciudad','id_poblacion');
    }

     public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rol')->withPivot('user_id','rol_id');
    }

    public function mensajes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('id_emisor','id_receptor');
    }

    public function subastas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subasta','id_creador','id');
    } 

    public function pujas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Puja','id_subasta','id');
    } 
}
```

When I put the password , the laravel create the user andthe field password in database is white.

Comment: pls may I see the code for your user model?

Comment: Shouldn't it `if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))`   ?

Comment: please can you show us the error message you got?

Comment: please can you change this `$usuario->password = \Hash::make('password');` to `$usuario->password = \Request::input('password');` and register a new user and try to login once more. This is because `public function setPasswordAttribute($password) { 
        $this->password = \Hash::make($password); 
    }` in the model will automatically hash the password before storing it in db

Comment: Hello @Digitlimit , I make this changes  and the field password in database is white , do you have an example about customize login and register to see how could I doing?

Comment: yes will past in answer. but before that, lets try more things. I can see your code looks okay. so the issue might persist even when use my own code

Comment: So, lets troubleshoot, lets ensure the password file has a value by doing this in : `public function registro(CreateUserRequest $request){ dd(Request::input('password'));}`

Comment: Yes , show the password with dd "123456789" , and I put my CreateUserRequest in the question.

Comment: I see that you have create a mutator inside your model for hashing the password, so I think the right approach is something like that.
 `$usuario->password=$usario-> setPasswordAttribute(\Request::input('password'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public function registro(CreateUserRequest $request){

            $file = $request->file('file');
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $fileName);


            $user = User::create([
                'nif' => $request->input('nif'),
                'name' => $request->input('name'),
                'cognoms' => $request->input('cognoms'),
                'birthday' => $request->input('birthday'),
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'password' => \Hash::make($request->input('password')),
                'file' => 'uploads/'.$fileName.'',
            ]);


            /**Asignamos el rol a la tabla intermedia***/
            $user = User::find($user->id);
            $user->roles()->attach(1);
            return redirect('/');


   }
```

Comment: The password field send white equal :( , I review all of my code another time.

Comment: what datatype is your password field. check your user migration table

Comment: Is the same   $table->string('password', 60) , I don't change this. I supose the order in the model it's one of the posibilities?

Comment: I delete the public function password in the model and I sent correctly the password into database  I think that in my opinion I have a problem with the setAttributePassword  I try your option and I have the same problem before I mentioned.

Comment: so lets go back to `$usuario->password= Hash::make(\Request::input('password'));` and also remove the setPasswordAttribute method from the model. Please also dd(Hash::make(\Request::input('password'))) in the registro() to see if it produces a hashed pasword

Comment: Hello @Digitlimit with the form that you mentioned  I recieve this recive the password hashed   "$2y$10$nX4ng6EoLoTOJke35rEsNecY9C/rWvMn7/RS/acSCIeUHQUca8oj2" ,

Comment: good. but did you say `$request->input('password')` is empty?

Comment: But with dd i show the password hash !! I don't know my problem I am stupid xd.

Comment: is it working now? please you are not stupid :). happens to anyone. please  confirm if your code is now working?

Comment: Yes , I have an error in the model , the code was correct however I think for this reason don't send the password.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove this `public function setPasswordAttribute($password) { 
        $this->password = \Hash::make($password); 
    }` I can't really spot any issue in your model